# Get data from function that returns Any

Tags: ios, swift, casting

Hello I'm new to swift and this is giving me some problems.
I have a function from SDK that returns `Any` as a result, this is what the actual data looks like:

```
/*{
    code = 1;
    msg = success;
    result =     {
        macAddress = "E6:1D:4D:71:64:9B";
    };
}*/
```

I figured out a way to get the data I need, but it seems quite convoluted.

```
sucBlock: {
    (mac) in
        if let macAddress = ((mac as AnyObject)["result"] as AnyObject )["macAddress"] as! Optional<String>{
                print("macAddress:" + macAddress)
            }
    }
```

Is there a better way to achieve this result? I tried to create a `struct` and type cast this object, but somehow it always failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to avoid using `AnyObject`  and `as!` in such cases

```
if let macAddress = mac as? [String:Any] , let item =  macAddress["result"] as? [String:String] , let str = item["macAddress"] {
    print("str:" + str)
}
```

If you need a struct ( Don't think it really deserves for your simple json )

```
do { 
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:mac)
    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from:data)
    print(res.result.macAddress)
}
catch { 
    print(error)
}
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let code: Int
    let msg: String
    let result: Result
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let macAddress: String
}
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to the question author and to future readers) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting code only.

Comment: I think it always deserves a struct, as you avoid all the nastiness of delving into the dictionary with keys, & you get the decoding for free

Comment: Thank you. Great explanation

Comment: I tried the struct example, but it failed: "failed decoding The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.". I can see that macAddress looks like a string, but what about "msg" parameter, it just says success without quotes.